# Нетипичное использование деепричастий, пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, деепричастия

```
1. Остановка будет не переходя дорогу. 
2. Не доезжая светофора будет остановка не переходя дорогу. 
3. Остановку не переходя дорогу снесло ветром.
```

Корректны ли предложения и какова пунктуация?

Comment: 1. Какова пунктуация? Вы не сделали ни попытки: не ясно, что здесь обсуждать. 2. Нетипичное использование деепричастий? Речь в вопросе о сомнительных предложениях и не о части речи, а оборотах.

Comment: Хочется ссылки, в которой рассматриваются подобные конструкции, она имеет собственное название, и это не деепричастные обороты. Обсуждать можно все, что касается данной конструкции. Приветствуются любые мысли

Answer (score 3):

Предложения ошибочны. Деепричастие задумывалось как такое причастие, которое будет относится к подлежащему, в каком бы положении относительно него оно не находилось (оторвано и перед или оторвано и после), поэтому предложения, где деепричастие не относится к подлежащему, считаются ошибкой, как, например, такое предложение: ‟Выйдя во двор, вороны набросились на меня”. (Относится к подлежащему в том смысле, что подлежащее должно либо выполнять действие, обозначенное деепричастием, либо подвергаться ему.) В итоге все эти предложения неверны, потому что деепричастие в них не относится к подлежащему.

[Ссылка на учебный материал (пункт 1).](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/786-36_predlozheniya_s_deeprichastnymi_oborotami.html)

Comment: "Деепричастие должно относиться к подлежащему". Не обязано. Например "Ему не хотелось курить, находясь в общественном месте"

Comment: Какие-то исключения там безусловно есть, особенно касающиеся предложений без подлежащего. Но точно не те, когда есть подлежащее и когда деепричастие к нему не относится (как в ваших предложениях).

Comment: И вообще я ни разу не слышал предложения как у вас, даже в сумбурной бытовой речи. Есть предложения типа: ‟Не доезжая до супермаркета, поверните налево”. Ваши предложения даже не взяты из сумбурной бытовой речи , а просто выдуманы.

Comment: Одно из них взято из коллективного труда лингвистов (порядка десяти авторов), сам я его тоже как-то использовал в бытовой речи. Но мне не нравится сама ваша установка. Если что-то выдумано, это не значит, что на него можно закрывать глаза, ну да дело хозяйское, без меня разберетесь.